# $http returns error code 0 sometimes and works sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have an angular controller that takes data from a form, manipulates the data and sends it to the server via `$http` to be saved

The issue is that the code works fine sometimes i.e it returns the success function and doesn't work sometimes i.e it returns error code 0 but even when this happens the data is still being saved in the database even the server log shows that its returning success, why is this?
The success function is called sometimes and sometimes the error one is called. What am I doing wrong?

**The angular controller is:**

```js
    app.controller("premiumAdvertsController",function($scope,ergastAPIservice,$routeParams,$location,$rootScope)
{
  function uploadImage(input,success) {
    console.log("yeh input hai ",input);
    if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
             success(e.target.result);
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
    }
}
      $scope.registerPremiumAdvertisement=function()
        {
          console.log("shakil k sath check!eeersss!");
          console.log("hello");
          var count=1;
          var owner=$rootScope.currentUser.email;
        var companyName=$scope.companyName;
        var companySlogan=$scope.companySlogan;
        var companyAddress=$scope.companyAddress;
        var companyFacebookLink=$scope.companyFacebookLink;
        var companyTwitterLink=$scope.companyTwitterLink;
        var companyContactNumber=$scope.companyContactNumber;
       var companySiteLink=$scope.companySiteLink;
       var sliderText=$scope.imageText;
       var category="premiumBrand";       
        var featuredOffer1Title=$scope.featuredOffer1Title;
        var featuredoffer1Description=$scope.featuredoffer1Description;
        var featuredoffer1Expiry=$scope.featuredoffer1Expiry;

        var featuredOffer2Title=$scope.featuredOffer2Title;
        var featuredoffer2Description=$scope.featuredoffer2Description;
        var featuredoffer2Expiry=$scope.featuredoffer2Expiry;

        var featuredOffer3Title=$scope.featuredOffer3Title;
        var featuredoffer3Description=$scope.featuredoffer3Description;
        var featuredoffer3Expiry=$scope.featuredoffer3Expiry;

        var featuredOffer4Title=$scope.featuredOffer4Title;
        var featuredoffer4Description=$scope.featuredoffer4Description;
        var featuredoffer4Expiry=$scope.featuredoffer4Expiry;
console.log("hello");
        var detailedOffer1Description=$scope.detailedOffer1Description;
        var detailedOffer2Description=$scope.detailedOffer2Description;
        var detailedOffer3Description=$scope.detailedOffer3Description;
        var detailedOffer4Description=$scope.detailedOffer4Description;
        console.log("hello");


        var storeName=$scope.storeName;
        var file1=document.getElementsByClassName("companyLogo")[0];
        var file2=document.getElementsByClassName("picture2")[0];
        var file3=document.getElementsByClassName("picture3")[0];
        var file4=document.getElementsByClassName("picture4")[0];
        var file5=document.getElementsByClassName("picture5")[0];
        console.log("hello");
        //var file6=document.getElementsByClassName("picture6")[0];
        //var file7=document.getElementsByClassName("picture7")[0];
        var f1,f2,f3,f4,f5;
        var out=[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5];
        var arr=[file1,file2,file3,file4,file5]

        for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++ )
        {

          console.log(i);
          
          if( arr[i].files[0])  
          {
            (function(ith){
              uploadImage(arr[ith],function(result){
              out[ith]=result;
              count++;
              console.log(count,"count");
              if(count==6)
              {
                console.log("count hogya six!");
                var featuredOffer1={offerTitle:featuredOffer1Title,offerDescription:featuredoffer1Description,offerExpiry:featuredoffer1Expiry};
                var featuredOffer2={offerTitle:featuredOffer2Title,offerDescription:featuredoffer2Description,offerExpiry:featuredoffer2Expiry};
                var featuredOffer3={offerTitle:featuredOffer3Title,offerDescription:featuredoffer3Description,offerExpiry:featuredoffer3Expiry};
                var featuredOffer4={offerTitle:featuredOffer4Title,offerDescription:featuredoffer4Description,offerExpiry:featuredoffer4Expiry};
                var featuredOffers=[];
                featuredOffers.push(featuredOffer1);
                featuredOffers.push(featuredOffer2);
                featuredOffers.push(featuredOffer3);
                featuredOffers.push(featuredOffer4);
                var pages=[];
                var pageCount=0;
        var offerDescriptions=[];
        var detailerOffer1={offerDescription:detailedOffer1Description,offerPicture:out[1]}
        var detailerOffer2={offerDescription:detailedOffer2Description,offerPicture:out[2]}
        var detailerOffer3={offerDescription:detailedOffer3Description,offerPicture:out[3]}
        var detailerOffer4={offerDescription:detailedOffer4Description,offerPicture:out[4]}
        offerDescriptions.push(detailerOffer1);
        offerDescriptions.push(detailerOffer2);
        offerDescriptions.push(detailerOffer3);
        offerDescriptions.push(detailerOffer4);

        var f={pageCount:pageCount,owner:owner,category:category,pages:pages,companyLogo:out[0],imageText:sliderText,companyName:companyName,companySlogan:companySlogan,companyAddress:companyAddress,companyContactNumber:companyContactNumber,companyFacebookLink:companyFacebookLink,companyTwitterLink:companyTwitterLink,companySiteLink:companySiteLink,featuredOffers:featuredOffers,offerDescriptions:offerDescriptions,premiumAdd:true};
        console.log("f bangya!");
        ergastAPIservice.saveHotBrand(f).then(function(res){
                    console.log("server pe chala gya data!");
                    if(res.success)
                    {
                      console.log("successfully got success from server !!");
                     $(".modalKaText").text("successfully uploaded");
              $("#myModal").modal();
              $location.path("/home");
                 }
                    else if(res.error)
                    {
                      console.log("got error from server!!!");
                      $(".modalKaText").text("There was some error");
              $("#myModal").modal();
              $location.reload()
                    }
                    else {
                      console.log("got nothing from server");
                    }
                },function(res){
                  res=JSON.stringify(res);
                  console.log("error found!!",res);
                })

              }
            })
            })(i);
            
          }
          else 
          {
            count++;
            console.log(count,"count");
          }

        }



      }
      
});
```

the code for the $http function (saveHotbrand) is :

```js
ergastAPI.saveHotBrand=function(abc)
    {
      return $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/saveAdd',
        data:abc
      })
    }
```

the nodejs and express code for this link is :

```js
  

app.post('/saveAdd',function(req,res){
 console.log("save add request!");
  var collection=req.db.get("advertisements");
  console.log("got database")
  collection.insert(req.body,function (err,doc){
    if(err)
    {
     console.log("sending error")
      res.send({error:true});
    }
    else {
     console.log("sending success")
      res.send({success:true});
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: You need to pair down this example.

Comment: i'm just trying to be as thorough as possible

Comment: Just as a side note: If you have different class names for same elements then use `id` or just use a general class name.

Comment: Also, your request times out I guess. Try waiting for the response for some suitable time after which you expect the response to come and if the request still times out, keep requesting until success. It is probably an issue from your server I guess.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui the thing is that the same code works EVERY ALTERNATE time.

Comment: @MohammadOmerTariq just looked on the mongo documentation. 0 error code returns on a successful exit so this means you are doing nothing wrong as your data is being fed into the database whatsoever just change your if condition to check if `err != 0`. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone coming now, the page was basically being redirected so I started to make the call to the controller function via ng-click instead of ngsubmit and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the nodejs code:

```
    app.post('/saveAdd',function(req,res){
    var collection=req.db.get("advertisements",function(err){
             collection.insert(req.body,function (err,doc){
             if(err)
             {   
                res.send({error:true});
             }
             else {
                 res.send({success:true});
             }

        })
    })

 })
```

I had faced a similar problem which was resolved by adding a callback function. You can see the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694841/rest-api-call-works-only-once).

Answer (score 0):

Change your eargast calling function to this
ergastAPIservice.saveHotBrand(f).success(function(res){
}

Then it will only work on success.

Comment: that was what the original code was, but the angular js documentation for $http clearly shows that success and error are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the form via click on a button and handling its click event to submit the form, whenever you do this you need to return false from the onCLick function apparently.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/exit-codes/) page, the error code 0 is actually a code for success, it's just your if condition that causes the problem. Include a check for `0` and it should work.